# How to evaluate datatype and true_of_all_constants functions?

Tags: function, functional-programming, sml, higher-order-functions

I am a beginner of sml and I'm taking programming language courses at Coursera. There's a datatype and function that I don't know how to evaluate:

```
datatype exp = constant of int
     | Negate of exp
     |Add of exp * exp
     |Multiply of exp * exp

fun true_of_all_constants(f,e) =
    case e of
    constant i => f i
      | Negate e1 => true_of_all_constants(f,e1)                
      | Add(e1,e2) => true_of_all_constants(f,e1)
              andalso true_of_all_constants(f,e2)
      | Multiply(e1,e2) => true_of_all_constants(f,e1)
              andalso true_of_all_constants(f,e2)
```

Trying to evaluate them, I always get errors:

```
true_of_all_constants [3,4,5];
true_of_all_constants 4;
true_of_all_constants (is_even 4, 5);
```

where is_even is a little helper function:

```
fun is_even v =
(v mod 2 = 0)
```

To test true_of_all_constants, what should e be replaced with? Also, could you explain what does datatype do here? I don't understand why we need "Negate" or "Add" here; why we have "exp*exp," rather than "exp+exp," for "Add?"

Comment: "*Trying to evaluate them, I always get errors*" - please show us the code you are trying to evaluate

Comment: "*could you explain what does datatype do here?*" - are you asking what the `datatype` keyword means here, or are you asking what the meaning and purpose of that particular `exp` datatype are?

Comment: @Bergi Updated my op. Please take a look. Thanks!

Comment: The call should rather look like `true_of_all_constants(is_even, Constant 4)` or `true_of_all_constants(is_even, Add(Negate(Constant 2), Multiply(Constant 3, Constant 4)))`

Comment: @Bergi What does "Add" do in "Add(Negate(Constant 2))?" Would it be (-2)+(-2)=-4?

Comment: It creates an instance of your datatype. It doesn't compute anything, it creates an abstract representation of such a mathematical expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing whitespace, the data type definition and the definition of `true_of_all_constants (p, e)` become:

```
datatype exp =
    Constant of int
  | Negate of exp
  | Add of exp * exp
  | Multiply of exp * exp

fun true_of_all_constants (p, e) =
    let fun aux (Constant i)        = p i
          | aux (Negate e1)         = aux e1
          | aux (Add (e1, e2))      = aux e1 andalso aux e2
          | aux (Multiply (e1, e2)) = aux e1 andalso aux e2
    in aux e end
```

Here `constant` has been renamed to `Constant`: Both will work, but naming constructors with an uppercase letter differentiates it visually from other identifiers. And I've used an inner function, `aux`, to shorten the recursive expressions a bit. Instead of `f` I called it `p` for *predicate*, but that's a taste thing.

> Trying to evaluate them, I always get errors

Here are some examples of expressions and evaluating them:

```
- val two_plus_two = Add (Constant 2, Constant 2);
- true_of_all_constants (fn i => i = 2, two_plus_two);
> val it = true : bool

- val two_times_neg_two = Multiply (Constant 2, Constant ~2);
- true_of_all_constants (fn i => i > 0, two_times_neg_two);
> val it = false : bool

- val two_four_six = Add (Constant 2, Add (Constant 4, Constant 6));
- fun is_even x = x mod 2 = 0;
- true_of_all_constants (is_even, two_four_six);
> val it = true : bool
```

> could you explain what does datatype do here?

I think you should refer to a book or tutorial here.

For example, [ML for the Working Programmer, ch. 4](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lp15/MLbook/pub-details.html) (free PDF) deals with `datatype` definitions.

> I don't understand why we need "Negate" or "Add" here

I don't know, either. The problem you're given in the course is entirely hypothetical.